# conditionalFormatting() with "databar" type used for more than once creates a corrupt file in openxlsx

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I have been facing this issue since a long time now. Whenever I try to generate an excel sheet containing `conditionalFormatting()` of type `"databar"` for more than one columns it creates a corrupt excel sheet.
The code to reproduce the error is below:

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook("myworkbook")
addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = "databar")

writeData(wb, "databar", -5:5, startCol = 5)
conditionalFormatting(wb, "databar",
                      cols = 5, rows = 1:11,
                      type = "databar", style = c("#a6a6a6"), showValue = FALSE
)

writeData(wb, "databar", -5:5, startCol = 7)
conditionalFormatting(wb, "databar",
                      cols = 7, rows = 1:11,
                      type = "databar", style = c("#a6a6a6"), showValue = FALSE, gradient = FALSE
)

writeData(wb, "databar", -5:5, startCol = 9)
conditionalFormatting(wb, "databar",
                      cols = 9, rows = 1:11,
                      type = "databar", style = c("#a6a6a6", "#a6a6a6"), showValue = FALSE, gradient = FALSE
)
saveWorkbook(wb, "sample.xlsx")
```

Comment: For me it also corrupts when writing just one column (i.e. just running the first `conditionalFormatting`). Is it really only for multiple columns for you?

Comment: This was reported as a bug, but it doesn't seem that it has been addressed: https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/385

Comment: Yeah it is crashing only for more than one columns for me.